# If $D$ is tangent point of $BC$ with incircle of $ABC$ and $T$ is intersection of $A$-mixtilinear inclrcle with $(ABC)$, then $\angle BTA=\angle CTD$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, plane-geometry

> Problem: Let $ABC$ be a triangle and let its incircle touch $BC$ at $D$. Let $T$ be the
>   tangency point of the $A$-mixtilinear incircle with circumcircle of $ABC$. Prove that $∠BTA = ∠CTD$.

I recognised that it suffices to show that $KT$ is isogonal to $DT$.Then the first thing that came to my mind is harmonic quadrilateral.I don't whether it is true or not.I am new to the topic of isogonals.  Help me how to start??[image]

Edit:I asked to prove that the above marked angles are equal.The question which marked as possible duplicate is not the same.Angles which were to be proven are different.I hope this convince you this as different question.I use mobile so geogebra in android is very difficult so I drew diagram manually.

Comment: With the MathJax issue aside (it is a minor issue in your question, but it is highly recommended that MathJax is used), a user of your reputation must have posted enough questions to know that a descriptive title is important.  "A Euclidean geometry question" or something alike is applicable to most geometry questions here.  Please also upload a diagram.

Comment: Concerning your edit: note that $\angle ATB = \angle ACB$ and use the linked question.